How can I add an origin to CORS in strapi v5?
I am facing the CORS error (The value of the 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header in the response must not be the wildcard '*' when the request's credentials mode is 'include'.) because origin was set to " * ", why is strapi ignoring the CORS configuration made in config/middlewares.ts? Even using a custom written CORS won't work because strapi will end up using his own.
export default [
  "strapi::logger",
  "strapi::errors",
  "strapi::security",
{
    name: 'strapi::cors',
    config: {
      enabled: true,
      header: '*',
      origin: ['http://localhost:3000']
    }
  },
  "strapi::poweredBy",
  "strapi::query",
  "strapi::body",
  "strapi::session",
  "strapi::favicon",
  "strapi::public",
];

What's causing the error is the withCredentials set to true in the httpConfig:
export const HTTP_CLIENT = axios.create({
    baseURL: ENV.API_URL,
    withCredentials: true,
});

how can I set an origin so I can use this?
Thank you

For my website portfolio, i'm using your stack, strapi + react. I haven't any configuration about strapi cors, beacuse i don't need to request strapi resources with credential, but the issue you are facing occurs because
withCredentials: true

in your Axios configuration requires the Access-Control-Allow-Origin header to match the domain making the request exactly. It cannot be set to a wildcard (*).
Maybe you can update the CORS middleware configuration in config/middlewares.ts: Ensure the middleware is set up to allow specific origins and credentials.
export default [
  "strapi::logger",
  "strapi::errors",
  "strapi::security",
  {
    name: "strapi::cors",
    config: {
      enabled: true,
      origin: ["http://localhost:3000"], // Specify your origin
      methods: ["GET", "POST", "PUT", "DELETE"], // Allow required methods
      headers: ["Content-Type", "Authorization"], // Include required headers
      credentials: true, // Allow credentials
    },
  },
  "strapi::poweredBy",
  "strapi::query",
  "strapi::body",
  "strapi::session",
  "strapi::favicon",
  "strapi::public",
];

Ensure Axios is correctly configured: Make sure the origin of the request matches the one specified in Strapi.
Use tools like browser DevTools or Postman to inspect response headers and ensure they include:
Access-Control-Allow-Origin
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials

I tried updating the configuration on CORS but in V5 strapi ignores the new configuration, when I go to check the request with DevTools I can see that the Access-Control-Allow-Origin is still '*' and not the origin I put in the config.

Try to update the Strapi in config/api.js: Strapi v5 has moved some configurations to the config/api.js file.
Ensure that the CORS settings are not overridden there.
Check or add the following:
module.exports = {
  rest: {
    cors: {
      enabled: true,
      origin: ["http://localhost:3000"],
    },
  },
};

